# Android image flickering in image in recyclerview

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

Everytime the list of images is updated in the recyclerview a slight image flicker occurs, I faced the same problem in GridView which was solved by setting a tag of images url in the holder like this,

```
//for solving image flicker
if(contentViewHolder.ivPhoto.getTag()==null || (!contentViewHolder.ivPhoto.getTag().equals(currentMoment.getThumbnailUrl()))){
            mImageLoader.displayImage(currentMoment.getThumbnailUrl(), contentViewHolder.ivPhoto);
        }

        contentViewHolder.ivPhoto.setTag(currentMoment.getThumbnailUrl());
```

This works great in a gridview however it doesnt solve the image flickering in case of recyclerview, can anyone suggest me how do I stop the image flickering in case of the recyclerview?

Comment: I'm also having this issue. It seems to have resurfaced with RecyclerView. When calling notifyDataSetChanged() the screen flickers, even if the data being displayed isn't changed. Other, pre-recyclerview, solutions list using ViewHolder (required by RecyclerView) and stable IDs (doesn't have any impact).

Comment: yes, havent found a solution yet, please notify me if you find any solution.

Comment: It seems that on a notifyDataSetChanged(), all the views are recycled... but they don't use the ones being displayed at the time, so the data all has to be updated... and the image reloaded. Even if the image is cached, there's still a flicker as the whole screen refreshes... not sure exactly what is causing it, though, or if it's just an internal issue.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change all list item then only use notifyDataSetChanged.
In other cases you should use :-

- notifyItemChanged(int)
- notifyItemInserted(int)
- notifyItemRemoved(int)

for more information refer following link of (official document)  :-
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29

Answer (score 1):

May be caused by another view being recycled.

Try reseting the view a the beginning of onBindViewHolder() with something like setImageDrawable(null);

Comment: I didn't get what you meant. Isn't reseting the view the reason behind the flicker?

Comment: The flicker is probably coming from the recycled view containing the previous image.  Then you asynchronously load the new image using  mImageLoader.displayImage.  So instead remove the previous image straight away and the new image will load into an empty view

Comment: I want to load the new image only if the url of the image in the viewholder at a particular position changes, reloading it everytime defeats the purpose